# Параметры обработки сообщения

Tags: winapi, delphi

Какие параметры у процедуры обработки сообщения WM_SYSCOMMAND?

Comment: У вас [**MSDN**][1] в городе отключили?)

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
procedure MessageProc(var msg: TWMSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;
```

Comment: Определение одноименной WinAPi функции такое:

      Function MessageProc (nCode:integer; wParam, LPARAM:Longint):Longint;

Comment: Речь в вопросе о [Message methods][1].

[Declaring a New Message-handling Method][2] - более подробно.

[1]:http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Message_Methods
[2]:http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_a_New_Message-handling_Method

Comment: Вообще-то, это неверный ответ, при том, что из коробки предлагается структура `TWMSysCommand`.

Comment: In order to handle more specific messages, the type of the var parameter **can** also be one of ... "Неверный" - значит не работает. По сути, да TWMSysCommand использовать правильнее.

Comment: Так отредактируйте! Там можно использовать такую структуру, что ни один враг не догадается, но работать оно будет.

Comment: Отредактировал :) На самом деле в msdn описана команда, которая не описана в TWMSysCommand - SC_MONITORPOWER...

Comment: Резонное замечание, при `SC_MONITORPOWER` `lParam` таки используется.